# Increasing Transfer speed between 2 servers on the same network

Tags: linux, networking, speed, cat6

I have 2 Linux servers sitting side-by-side. I transfer large files From *Server A* to *Server B*.

The transfer speed is slow, it shows up as **11.2MB/s**.

What are ways to increase this?
Should I use CAT6 cables? 
I'm confused on why I can't get at least 100MB/s with the current setup.

Our Network switch does support 10/100/1000.

I am open to suggestions, and I apologize if this is a noob question.

I am a programmer, so networking isn't one of my skills.

Here is the statistics from SCP command:

[image: Statistics from SCP command]

Comment: What are the network cards in the servers? Maybe they don't permit more than 10/100. Does the router have a setting where it limits transfer speeds? Do you get higher speeds with other devices in the same network?

Comment: 11.2MB/s sounds a lot like the speed of a 100 Mb network.  Make sure your two Linux boxes are running at 1Gb.  You can check with the ethtool command, such as `ethtool eth0` or `ethtool eno1` and look for the line that says something like `Speed: 100Mb/s` or `Speed: 1000Mb/s`

Comment: @virtex I see "Speed: 1000Mb/s"

Comment: The other server is "Speed: 100Mb/s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of networks is measured in bits per second, for example 100 Megabits per second is written as 100 Mbps (lowercase b).

The transfer speeds you see in SCP are in bytes per second (MB/s) (uppercase B).

So, roughly you are having 11.2 MBPS x 8 = 89.6 Mbps, that is a value near to 100 Mbps.

Check the configuration of the network cards and the switch ports to be sure that you can connect to 1000 Mbps.

Comment: He's asking why he is not getting gigabit speeds, as his switch does acutally support ist.

Comment: @kyze he says: `I'm confused on why I can't get at least 100MB/s with the current setup`. He`s getting there.

Comment: We are currently working on solving the issue after further troubleshooting. We are scheduling the downtime for users and will begin upgrading cable/switch.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After changes, ethtool eth0 displays speeds of Speed: 1000Mb/s